# Loop through variables and allocate values

Tags: php

I have a form with 20 rows and 10 columns and the element ids are distinguished by _r1, _r2 etc. and rather than assign all of the values manually from my query, I was hoping to loop through them.

Something like

```
//Set all mileage fields to empty
for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) {
    $strTravelDate_r.$i = "";
    $strHBE_r.$i = "";
    $strPassenger_r.$i = "";
    $strCongestionCode_r.$i = "";
    $strTravelReason_r.$i = "";
    $strAddress1_r.$i = "";
    $strAddress2_r.$i = "";
    $strDistance_r.$i = "";
    $strRate_r.$i = "";
    $strLineAmount_r.$i = "";
}

//Get mileage claims
$sql_miles = 'SELECT * FROM `tblsaved_mileage` WHERE `strUsername`="'.addslashes($username).'"';
$rs_miles = mysql_query($sql_miles);
$count_miles = mysql_num_rows($rs_miles);
$i = 1;
if ($count_miles > 0) {
    while ($row_miles = mysql_fetch_array($rs_miles)) {
        $strTravelDate_r.$i = $row_miles['strTravelDate'];
        $strHBE_r.$i = $row_miles['strHBE'];
        $strPassenger_r.$i = $row_miles['strPassenger'];
        $strCongestionCode_r.$i = $row_miles['strCongestionCode'];
        $strTravelReason_r.$i = $row_miles['strTravelReason'];
        $strAddress1_r.$i = $row_miles['strAddress1'];
        $strAddress2_r.$i = $row_miles['strAddress2'];
        $strDistance_r.$i = $row_miles['strDistance'];
        $strRate_r.$i = $row_miles['strRate'];
        $strLineAmount_r.$i = $row_miles['strAmount'];

        $i = $i + 1;
    }
}
```

But I get a load of

```
Notice: Undefined variable: strTravelDate_r in ........

Notice: Undefined variable: strHBE_r in ........

Notice: Undefined variable: strPassenger_r in ........
```

Comment: What's the reason you did that and not used an array to hold the values?

Comment: PHP has variable variables, but that's not the syntax for tham. While I could show you the correct syntax, I won't, because you should use arrays instead.

Comment: It would probably be wise to start by adding a `LIMIT 20` in your query, since you only allocate 20 variables...
I would also recommend using arrays instead of variable variables in this case.

Comment: @Barmar thanks to you I've just discovered variable variables. What a weird construct, honestly.

Answer (score 2):

Use an array, not variable variables:

```
$results = array();
while ($row_miles = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_miles)) {
    $results[] = $row_miles;
}
```

Now you can access `$results[$i]['strTravelDate']`, for example.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I'll give it a go. Do I then echo $results[0], $results[1] etc in my form?

Comment: No, you echo `$results[0]['columnName']`, like I showed. Please study PHP arrays, I'm not a beginning programming tutor.

Comment: Thanks. 1) it was your choice to answer the question. 2) if your suggestion is to go away and get the answer elsewhere, this forum is obsolete. Nonetheless, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is totally wrong, from the choice of MySQL library (obsolete extension by now) to the way you assign variables. You use an array for such purpose. Also, if you use PDO - all that mess up there that you created becomes this (assuming you created a $pdo object using PHP'S PDO class):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tblsaved_mileage` WHERE `strUsername` = ?");

$stmt->execute(array($username));

$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // And now you have all of your data in $results array
```

No need for initializing N variables, no need to use obsolete mysql_* extension, no need to loop trough the record set you get, no need to use addslashes etc. and you end up with less code.

Comment: Thanks NB. They don't have PDO installed at work and getting IT to do anything is like getting blood from a stone. I could use mysqli but that would involve a huge amount of work recoding (for no real gain). I take your point re using an array - that's why I'm here asking the question.

Comment: I feel you on the IT topic, but still the principle applies. As Barmar said in his answer, an array here solves your problems. If you're unfamiliar how to use them, then that's another topic :)